# Manejar fecha y hora con Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

En este momento me encuentro desarrollando mi aplicación web, la cual dispone de competiciones. Estas competiciones tienen, entre otros, estos dos campos:

-deadline, datetime

-finished, booblean

En primer lugar, necesito saber como puedo hacer para que el usuario pueda escoger en deadline el año, mes, dia, horas y minutos. He probado con un `date_select`, pero solo puedo escoger año, mes y día.

Por otro lado, quiero que cuando la hora y fecha del sistema sea la misma que `deadline`, el campo `finished` cambie a `true`, ¿Cómo se consigue esto en rails? ¿Tiene que estar constantemente haciendo la comprobación el sistema?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué uso darás al campo `finished`?

Comment: Ese campo se pondrá a true cuando se cumpla  deadline = hora del sistema. Básicamente para saber si una competición ha terminado o no, ya que me hace falta para siguientes pasos en el proceso de la competición (se trata de competiciones de diferentes fases, donde cada fase la trato como una competición única)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...como puedo hacer para que el usuario pueda escoger en deadline el
>   año, mes, dia, horas y minutos

Utiliza `select_datetime`, el cual te proporcionará campos para año, mes, día, hora, minutos y segundos.

> ...cuando la hora y fecha del sistema sea la misma que `deadline`, el
>   campo `finished` cambie a `true`, ¿Cómo se consigue esto en rails?

La manera más sencilla es utilizar alguna gema para la programación de tareas (e.g. [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), entre otras), con la que programes una tarea cada vez que generes un registro de *competición* nuevo.

Por ejemplo, podrías crear un método en tu modelo (para el ejemplo lo llamo `Competicion`) que se encargue de actualizar el campo `finished` y enviar el correo de notificación<sup>1</sup>:

```
class Competicion < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def fin_competicion
    self.update(:finished, true)
    CompeticionMailer.fin(self).deliver_now
  end
end
```

Y programarías la tarea desde tu controlador utilizando *Delayed Job*<sup>2</sup>:

```
class CompeticionController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def create
    @competicion = Competicion.new(competicion_params)

    if @competicion.save
      @competicion.delay(run_at: @competicion.deadline).fin_competicion
      # código para creación exitosa
    else
      # código para creación no exitosa
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>*Se asume que ya fue creado el* mailer *`CompeticionMailer` con el método `fin`.*</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>*Se asume que* Delayed Job *ya ha sido instalado y configurado.*</sup>

Comment: El problema es que el sistema ha de avisarme, por notificación ya implementada, de que la competición ha terminado. Por lo que no sé si hay alguna alternativa a comprobación continua

Comment: @JorgeVelaPlaza He actualizado mi respuesta para considerar tu comentario.

Comment: se me ocurre restar deadline-time.now cuando creo una competición. La diferencia me daría en segundos, entonces pasarla a horas minutos y días y hacer una tarea para que se ejecute transcurridos esos días, horas y minutos. ¿Con qué gema o cómo debería hacerlo? ¿Se le puede indicar eso a un delayed_job?

Comment: @JorgeVelaPlaza Sí podrías hacerlo, pero considero que sería innecesario ya que la tarea la puedes programar con `deadline` directamente, y obtendrías el mismo resultado. ¿Alguna razón en particular por la que quieras hacerlo así?

Comment: Vale, ya entiendo. Entonces la linea `@competicion.delay(run_at: @competicion.deadline).fin_competicion` se ejecutará cuando la hora del sistema sea igual a deadline no?. Si es así, ya tengo resuelta mi duda. Y no, no haría falta entonces hacer lo que he puesto antes, como bien dices

Comment: @JorgeVelaPlaza Exacto, con esa línea especificas día y hora (al segundo) en la que debe ejecutarse la tarea.

Comment: Genial! Como siempre  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Para escoger fecha y hora, lo más simple es usar `select_datetime`. Ahora si no quieres tener lleno de selects y usar algo más funcional y bonito, podrías probar con una librería javascript como [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). También hay una [gema](https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails) que te facilita la integración de esta funcionalidad.

Ahora, respecto de tu implementación, como primera cosa un detalle: creo que el campo `finished` está de más. Podrías perfectamente definir un método que reemplace su función:

```
def finished?
  deadline < Time.current
end
```

para consultar la BD tampoco sería necesario:

```
def self.finished
  where('deadline < ?', Time.current)
end
```

algo más útil podría ser marcar en la BD si se envió o no la notificación para esa competición.
Ahora, respecto al problema de fondo, no es algo simple de implementar, porque efectivamente necesitarías un proceso consultando constantemente a la BD por las competiciones que hayan superado el deadline, tampoco hay algo nativo en rails que te permita realizar lo que pides. Las soluciones que se me ocurren son:

- Lo más fácil sería crear un rake task que realice la consulta y notificaciones y programarlo con [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) para que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo. El problema de esta implementación es que al ejecutar un rake task, te inicia un nuevo proceso de rails aparte del que ya estás corriendo, lo cual consume tiempo, memoria y cpu, así que agendar para que se ejecute, por poner un ejemplo, cada 1 minuto ya es bastante y lo más seguro que más pronto que tarde vas a tener problemas de rendimiento en tu servidor.
- Integrar [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions) en tu proyecto que es una forma mucho mas liviana de manejar tareas ya que las ejecuta a través de threads en vez de un proceso entero como lo haría un task. Entonces al momento de que se cree o actualice el deadline de la competición, agendar una comprobación para la fecha del deadline para ver si ésta ha terminado. Tus opciones son:

  - Usar algo como `competicion.delay_until(competicion.deadline + 5.seconds).envia_notificacion` (puedes agregarle unos segundos para darle un tiempo de margen y que envíe la notificación cuando corresponda). Esta es la opción más simple, sin embargo consume más recursos, ya que serializa el objecto actual y lo pone en memoria.
  - Crear un worker y ejecutar algo como `NotificaWorker.perform_at(competicion.deadline, competicion.id)`. Esto te lleva solo un poco más de trabajo, pero es mucho más liviano para sidekiq, ya que solo le estás enviando el id de la competición, la cual obviamente debe ser buscada desde dentro del worker.

  el problema de integrar sidekiq es que tienes que instalar un nuevo servicio (redis) y que eventualmente podrías tener problemas de notificaciones que no sean enviadas si no haces las validaciones que correspondan o que queden agendadas notificaciones que no se realicen nunca. En el fondo, hacer tu lógica que envía las notificaciones tolerante a fallos o situaciones excepcionales. Solo un ejemplo, imagina un troll que te llene de competiciones con deadline al año 2100, competiciones que no se notificarán en muchas décadas y que poco a poco le irán quitando memoria a notificaciones que si la necesitan. En el peor caso te saturará la memoria y matará el server.

¿Que eligiría yo? Una combinación de ambas soluciones, empezando con integrar sidekiq y en caso de que te encuentres que hay notificaciones que de todas formas no se están enviando por XYZ razón que pueda estar sucediendo, hacer un barrido final con un rake task cada cierta cantidad de horas revisando para qué competiciones aún no se envían sus notificaciones.

Comment: Otra opcion para cambiar `finished` a `true` podria ser que creara un programa totalmentee aparte a la aplicacion web de rails (el cual podria ser programado en otros lenguajes inclusive) que se conecte a la base de datos, haga las comprobaciones y realize el cambio de `finished`, no deberia ser un programa muy grande, y para hacer que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo se podria usar el comando `cron` de Linux.

Comment: @AlterLagos se me ocurre restar deadline-time.now cuando creo una competición. La diferencia me daría en segundos, entonces pasarla a horas minutos y días y hacer una tarea para que se ejecute transcurridos esos días, horas y minutos. ¿Con qué gema o cómo debería hacerlo? ¿Se le puede indicar eso a whenever?